# How to set the order in which validations are performed when using @Valid?

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, validation

I'm using the @Valid annotation to perform validations after a form submit. (Spring MVC 3.1 & the JSR 303 implementation is Hibernate Validator)

Error messages are then displayed in the page based on these validations.

The problem is that I need to control how these messages are displayed (in other words, **in which order** they are displayed). I want them to appear in the same order as the fields appear in my page.

I know it can be done by using groups, but it seems like a patch to me. Groups don't seem to be meant for that... but maybe I'm wrong?!?
And also, I don't want to define a group (a new interface) for each property of my bean... it needs to be simpler than that...

So, my question ... is there a proper way to set the order in which validations will be performed?

Thanks.

Comment: This is just a display issue.  Why is the order so important?

Comment: Aaron, when I looked into this the order was important because using the @Valid annotation would return an error for the first arbitrary validation failure the validator encountered. Only getting one error at a time, I wanted the client to display error messages in a predictable order. Imagine a series of form inputs that the user fills out sequentially down the page--it would be strange if the fields were highlighted with errors or tooltips in a random fashion, instead of one after the other down the page, for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper way... groups are the closest thing to a standard approach, unfortunately. Hopefully this will change soon!

Answer (score -1):

You can use spring `form:errors` tag in you jsp:

```
<form:errors path="varName" />
<form:input path="varName" cssClass="small" disabled="${isFormDisabled}"/>
```